# Why is Electron not running my preload script?

Tags: electron

I'm trying to use a [preload script](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) to work around a [CORS header issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7931) in Electron 4.2.3. However, I can't get the preload script to run. A minimal reproduction case:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.2.3"
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.on('ready', function() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      preload: `file://${__dirname}/preload.js`,
    }
  })
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
  win.loadFile('index.html')
})
```

**preload.js**

```
window.preloadWasRun = 'preload was run'
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <script>
    document.write(window.preloadWasRun || 'preload was not run')
  </script>
</body>
```

No matter what settings I use for `webSecurity`, `nodeIntegration` and `contextIsolation`, it seems that my `preload` script is just getting ignored. Even if I make a syntax error in the script, it doesn't show any errors anywhere.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out it has to be an absolute path name, not an absolute URL. None of these work:

```
      preload: `file://${__dirname}/preload.js`,
      preload: './preload.js',
      preload: 'preload.js',
```

But this works as advertised:

```
      preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
```

Since it seems to be a filesystem path rather than a URL, it might also be wise to use `path.join` instead, to account for platforms with weird path separators:

```
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
```